# Keyboard method for opening the Mac's On-screen Keyboard

Tags: macos, on-screen-keyboard

I need a keyboard method for opening the Mac's On-screen Keyboard.
I could be a Terminal command.
The string will be injected into user's Mac's USB port by our device; "Voila, an OSK!"

Answer (score 2):

See [this solution](https://github.com/nriley/keyboardViewer) for Mac OS X 10.6.

On Mac OS X 10.5, you can open the following program:

> `/System/Library/Components/KeyboardViewer.component/Contents/SharedSupport/KeyboardViewerServer.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyboardViewerServer`

Answer (score 2):

At least in 10.7 and later you can just open the KeyboardViewer application:

```
open -a KeyboardViewer
```

It has a few drawbacks though:

- If you close the keyboard window by for example pressing the close button, the KeyboardViewer process stays running and keeps using something like 0-10% CPU.
- If you open KeyboardViewer again after that, it doesn't reopen the keyboard window.
- The keyboard window is made visible when I run scripts that emulate keystrokes or use Alfred's clipboard history.

All of those can be avoided by opening the keyboard window from the input menu:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 where description is "text input") of menu bar 1
        click
        click (menu item 1 where title ends with "Keyboard Viewer") of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

A workaround for the second issue is to terminate KeyboardViewer if it is running but has no windows:

```
if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
    tell application "System Events" to number of windows of process "KeyboardViewer"
    if result is 0 then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
        delay 0.1
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"
    else
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    end if
else
    activate application "KeyboardViewer"
end if
```