# Where is the MacOS on-screen keyboard located in the file system?

Tags: macos

If I were to run this from the Terminal, how could I run the on-screen keyboard similarly to the option in the Show Emojis & Symbols icon in the menu bar?

Comment: Try this command: `/System/Library/Input\ Methods/KeyboardViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyboardViewer`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard method for opening the Mac's On-screen Keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/293237/keyboard-method-for-opening-the-macs-on-screen-keyboard)

Comment: I'm on Big Sur and it doesn't open. @harrymc